# advertising on cooking.stackexchange ?

Tags: support

Does this platform support advertising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, community ads can be submitted and voted upon in [this designated thread](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1056/60).

If you have a product or service you wish to advertise you can [contact stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) directly.